# check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 't' at line 1"

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using express node.js with mysql to build the api's and want to connect these api's to the front end but i have face an error, due to this my application didn't run properly plzzzz tell me whats the problem in my code.

code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
errno: 1064,
sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 't' at line 1",
sqlState: '42000',
index: 0,
sql: 't'

```js
const pool = require('../../config/database');

module.exports = {
    create:(data, callback) =>{
        pool.query(
            `insert into registration(firstname,lastname,gender,email,password,number) 
            values(?,?,?,?,?,?)`,
            [
                data.firstname,
                data.lastname,
                data.gender,
                data.email,
                data.password,
                data.number,
            ],
            (error, result, fields) =>{
                if (error) {
                    callback(error)
                }
                return callback(null, result)
            }
        )
    },
    
    getUsers: callback =>{
        pool.query(
            `select id,firstname,lastname,gender,email,number from registration`,
            [],
            (error, results, fields) =>{
                if (error) {
                    callback(error);
                }
                return callback(null, results);
            }
        )
    },
    getUserByUserId: (id, callback) => {
        pool.query(
            `select id,firstname,lastname,gender,email,number from registration where id =?`,
            [id],
            (error, results, fields) =>{
                if (error) {
                    callback(error)
                }
                return callback(null, results[0])
            }
        )
    },
    updateUser: (data, callback) =>{
        pool.query(
            `update registration set firstname=?, lastname=?, gender=?, email=?, password=?, number=? where id=?`
            [
                data.firstname,
                data.lastname,
                data.gender,
                data.email,
                data.password,
                data.number,
                data.id
            ],
            (error, results, fields) =>{
                if (error) {
                    callback(error)
                }
                return callback(null, results)
            }
        )
    },
    deleteUser: (data, callback) =>{
        pool.query(
            `delete from registration where id =?`,
            [data,id],
            (error, results, fields) => {
                if (error) {
                  return callback(error);
                }
                return callback(null, result[0]);
            }
        )
    }
};
```

*emphasized text*

Comment: Can you narrow down the problem?